# Push notifications not received in Production Environment

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have created an application that should receive push notifications. Unfortunately, the push notifications are only received in a test environment and not in a production environment.

I have checked all I had to check, I also created an app with provisioning "ad-hoc", but unfortunately nothing I do solves the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive notification in a production environment, you have to generate yor app with production certification and generate your .p12 file with all production file and certification.

Comment: Yes, i generate my app with production certification and i generate .p12

Comment: I don't undeterstand this. This is ("[16777217] transmitted {"aps":{"badge":1,"alert":"Hello World"}} on first attempt to token 3f411..a5bd2") the response of Apple after send notification. I see that Apple response with notification transmitted..Why ?

Comment: How about your device_token. Device token you get in dev environment is different from pro environment. Do you upload your device_token correctly?

Comment: Yes is correct. If is not correct Apple response with invalid token

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
The problem was the digital certificate for the service of apn for the production of Apple 
I had to recreate the certificate following this forum:

[Cannot send push notifications using Javapns/Javaapns SSL handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585858/cannot-send-push-notifications-using-javapns-javaapns-ssl-handshake-failure)

Thank you all.