# Push Notification issue with Telerik Hybrid App

Tags: ios, push-notification, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app, telerik-appbuilder

I am trying to implement PUSH notification in my Hybrid Application. I followed the procedures as specified in the link below.

[TELERIK PUSH NOTIFICATION TUTORIAL](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/javascript/push-notifications/introduction.html)

I have production certificate and corresponding APNS Certificate. Along with this i have the app manager push notification certificate. So the 2 APNS are mapped to my production certificate. I am able to register my devices for the push notification and can view them in the devices section. But when i try to send the push notification i get the following error.

> **Apple notification service connection couldn't be established due to invalid key/certificate.**

The push notification for the Telerik App Manager Works fine and i am having issue with the push notification to my App. I tried recreating the certificates and still having issue. The app that i am trying to create is an enterprise app.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem....

Comment: in case server side is JAVA see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836487/apns-cant-send-notification-to-ios-device-using-java/35863962?noredirect=1#comment59406477_35863962

Comment: @sheshnath Sorry i have a back end and its in .Net. In the case of Telerik we can use their own backend for push notifications.

Comment: for creating certificate check this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: make sure your WWDR certificate is not expired,https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: @sheshnath I have another application in my account and push notification to that app works fine. So i dont think there is any issue with WWDR certificate.

Comment: once certificate is exported on server, later on even if WWDR does expired it doesn't make impact on already running certificate on server. please check this, and make sure date and time of your PC is accurate.

Comment: @sheshnath I just checked and the certificate is fine.

Comment: last option, delete all certificates(APNS), provisioning profile and make it from scratch :)

Comment: @sheshnath I did that already and i have mentioned it in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much debugging and test runs i got a solution for this. The tutorial in Telerik Doc does not specify which certificate is to be uploaded in the back end.

In the Telerik backend we need to upload the APNS p12 certificate and not the apps p12 certificate.

Hope this helps some who encounters the same scenario.